# How can I add variable value to a select query result in Codeigniter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a select query which outputs several rows. Query is working but what I need is, I want to insert a custom column with value into the above result.
I am using Codeigniter 3 with PostgreSQL. The query looks like,

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 6;
```

The result I got is something like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Adventure Honeymoon
            [nights] => 5
            [price] => ₹37,000.00
            [discount] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Wild Side Of Kerala
            [nights] => 4
            [price] => ₹24,000.00
            [discount] => 0
        )
...
)
```

I want to add a custom column named 'category' with the result, which should looke like the below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Adventure Honeymoon
            [nights] => 5
            [price] => ₹37,000.00
            [discount] => 0
            [category] => Honeymoon Tours                                                                                     
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Wild Side Of Kerala
            [nights] => 4
            [price] => ₹24,000.00
            [discount] => 0
            [category] => Wild Life Tours                                                                                     
        )
...
)
```

Quick help will be appreciated.

Comment: From where to get or assign category values?

Comment: @jainvikram444 I have an array of customised category lists.

Comment: It's inside of database table or in array of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Model**

```
public function get_data(){
   $query = $this->db->select('*')
   ->from('tlb_name')
   ->order_by('timestamp', 'ASC')
   ->limit(6)
   ->get();
   return $query->result_array();  

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function custom_addition(){

   $data = $this->model_name->get_data();

   foreach($data as $row){
       $row['category'] = 'Value';
   }

   print_($data);

}
```

`$data` the result of query

Comment: This worked a bit, only producing the last result row while I return the result in model to controller. There are 6 rows in the query result.

Comment: Only last row getting the value of `$data['category']` ?

Comment: All I get is a single row while there are 6 rows if I run the query and return the same without looping with foreach.

Comment: After the foreach loop check the data first `print_r($data);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191910/discussion-between-jerry-jones-and-danish-ali).

Answer (score 0):

You will add column and add values as per condition using case or static or joining tables.
You have to change ? to values/column_name as per requirement:

```
SELECT T1.*, (case when T1.column_name = ? then ? else ? end) as 'CutomColumnName'
FROM TableName T1
ORDER BY T1.timestamp ASC
 LIMIT 6;
```

Ex:

```
SELECT T1.*, 
   (case when T1.CategoyId=1 then 'Category-1'  
         when T1.CategoyId=2 then 'Category-2'
         else 'Not Found'
    end) as 'CutomColumnName'
    FROM TableName T1
    ORDER BY T1.timestamp ASC
     LIMIT 6;
```

Or

```
SELECT T1.*, C1.name 
FROM TableName T1
left outer join category C1 on C1.id=T1.category_id
ORDER BY T1.timestamp ASC
 LIMIT 6;
```